# grep -f alternative sed?awk?

Tags: sed, awk, grep

```
file1 = 95000
file2 = 4500000
```

I want to filter out file1 entries from file2.

```
egrep -f file1 file2
```

takes ages to complete.
Is there an alternative ? sed? awk?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sure, you can use `awk`. Put `file2` entries into an array. Then iterate `file1`, each time finding those entries in the array.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0];next}($0 in a)' file2 file1
```

Play around with these options to get what you want

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0];next}(!($0 in a))' file2 file1
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0];next}(!($0 in a))' file1 file2
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0];next}($0 in a)' file1 file2
```

Comment: Will this filter out file1 from file2? Like egrep -vf file1 file2 ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `grep -f` is really meant to work with a filter file of that size so some sort of database backed solution might be your best bet.

You could load both files line-by-line into an SQLite database and then do a simple bit of SQL something like this:

```
SELECT line FROM file2
EXCEPT
SELECT line FROM file1
```

and dump them back out. You could do all of that straight from the command line with SQLite.